# How to rename the folder in java

Tags: java, directory, rename

My folder structure looks like

```
D:
|- Folder1
   |- File1
|- Folder2
   |- File2
```

output:

```
D:
|- Directory1   <- renamed
   |- File1 
|- Directory2   <- renamed
   |- File2
```

The question is how to rename the folders one level down?

Comment: use an IDE and refactor your code/structure

Comment: I have tried with nio. but It is complex to stop at one level. With out nio I dont know how to control with levels..

Comment: What kind of IDE do you use?

Comment: Eclipse is the IDE

Comment: You already ask other questions how to rename a file/folder in java, which had also a working code. But in on [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48320280/8097737) was a `AccessDeniedException` thrown. So is this really a problem related to java? Can you rename the specific folders with other tools?

Comment: @devpuh Check the comment of that answer that didnot solved and I have updated the question aswell. yes of course this is related to java

Comment: @DineshRavi I know, but this doesn't answer the question "can you rename the folder with other tools?". Also it's possible that you can't rename a file/folder even when you have all permissions, since its locked.

Comment: @devpuh I dont know any other tool other that manually renaming each folder. but there are > 1000 folders.

Comment: @DineshRavi so can you manually rename one of those files which causes the trouble?

Comment: @devpuh yes, manually I can rename all the folders and files.

Comment: @DineshRavi When you can manually rename all these files and folders (without any warnings) it should be possible to rename them with the code you provided. I guess: The question is not why the code doesn't work, but rather how the environment affects it. What and how are this files/folders created? Does the program still run which created (or works with) the files/folders? In your code to create the new name you use `replaceAll`, do you ensure that there didn't already exist a a file/folder with this name.

Comment: @devpuh I found a way to solve the above problem. Check my answer below

Comment: @DineshRavi so the problem was that two or more folders share the same name after renaming? (e.g.: "Folder1" and "Folder2" are both renamed to "Directory")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved my problem.

1. I get the directory present at specified depth.
2. Create new directory with altered name
3. Used FileUtils ([Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)) to copy the files to the new folder.
4. Manually delete all those old folder.

---

```
package com.so.practice;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Sof {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<File> files = getDirs(new File("path to root folder"), 0); //level 0 is inside parent , level 1, and so on
        System.out.println(files);
        String[] paths = new String[files.size()];

        int i = 0;
        for (File file : files) {
            paths[i++] = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        String matchword = "Folder1";

        //File  f = null;
        HashMap<String, String > old_new = new HashMap<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < paths.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(paths[j]);
            String old_path = paths[j];
            String foldername = new File(paths[j]).getName();
            //02_PA__OPCON.MES.GC.Configuration 
            //02_Configuration

            if(old_path.contains(matchword)){
                paths[j] =paths[j].replaceAll(matchword, "Directory");

                old_new.put(old_path, paths[j]);

            }else{
                System.out.println("skipping->"+old_path);
            }
            //f = new File(paths[j]);
            //f.mkdirs();
        }

        for(String key : old_new.keySet()){
            FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(key), new File(old_new.get(key)));
        }

        //FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(old_new.get), new File(arg0));
     }

     static List<File> getDirs(File parent, int level){
        List<File> dirs = new ArrayList<File>(); //to store 
        for(File f: parent.listFiles()){
            if(f.isDirectory()) {
                if (level==0) dirs.add(f);
                else 
                    if (level > 0) dirs.addAll(getDirs(f,level-1)); //recursion
            }
        }
        return dirs;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are aware that [`FileUtils.copyDirectory`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory-java.io.File-java.io.File-) overrides existing files in the destination directory when it already exists?

Comment: @devpuh Thanks I dont know that

Answer (score 15):

```
File dir = new File(dirPath);
if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
  System.err.println("There is no directory @ given path");
} else {
    System.out .println("Enter new name of directory(Only Name and Not Path).");
    String newDirName = scanner.nextLine();
    File newDir = new File(dir.getParent() + "\" + newDirName);
    dir.renameTo(newDir);
}
```

Comment: Avoid the use of `System.exit(0);`

Comment: If you need to make not OS based path, instead of

File newDir = new File(dir.getParent() + "\" + newDirName);
use 
File newDir = new File(dir.getParent() + File.separator + newDirName);